# How do I take a list of integers, take the function letter_grade and print 'The grade is A' for example.

Tags: python

Here is the code I have, I want to know how I can take a list of integers (scores) and call a function and prints some like 'The grade is A' and so on.

```
def letter_grade():
score = input('Enter your test score: ')
if score < 60:
    print 'The grade is E'
elif score < 70:
    print 'The grade is D'
elif score < 80:
    print 'The grade is C'
elif score < 90:
    print 'The grade is B'
else:
    print 'The grade is A' 
return score


letter_grade()
```

Comment: the code you have is correct if it has proper indent. Given a list of integers, you can use a for-loop and letter_grade() you defined to have the 'ABC' kind of scores. Is it correct ?

Comment: I am trying to use number scores actually, something like 97, 84, 32, 67, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by making your function take a parameter

```
def letter_grade(score):    
    if score < 60:
        print 'The grade is E'
    elif score < 70:
        print 'The grade is D'
    elif score < 80:
        print 'The grade is C'
    elif score < 90:
        print 'The grade is B'
    else:
        print 'The grade is A' 
    return score


score = int(raw_input('Enter your test score: '))
letter_grade(score)
```

Since you're using Python2, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`

It's not nice to mix the logic and the printing in the same function, so let's *return* just the grade

```
def letter_grade(score):    
    if score < 60:
        return 'E'
    elif score < 70:
        return 'D'
    ... and so on



score = int(raw_input('Enter your test score: '))
print "The grade is {}".format(letter_grade(score))
```

Notice that we are now using `format` to insert the grade into the string. Now for a `list` of scores

```
list_of_scores = range(50, 100, 5)  # a list of scores [50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95]
for score in list_of_scores:
    print "The grade is {}".format(letter_grade(score))
```

Comment: Remember that `str.format()` was added in Python 2.6, so if you're using an earlier version (hopefully not) you might use something like `print "The grade is %s" % letter_grade(score)` which incidentally will work in later versions as well.

Comment: @MattDMo, Right, but If someone is learning Python <2.6 these days they better have a very good reason. (work perhaps)

Comment: just trying to be backwards compatible :)

Comment: I get a error when putting in the numbers in the range() TypeError: range expected at most 3 arguments, got 4

Comment: also it only prints the first number in range()

Comment: I think I fixed it, I just say list_of_scores = [1, 2, 3, 4] instead